# Log4j don't work in my class

Tags: java, log4j

Well, the log4j don't work and i don't know why. See my properties bellow:

```
#### Usando 2 appenders, 1 para logar no console, outro para um arquivo
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG,stdout,fileOut

# Imprime somente mensagens com 'priority' WARN ou mais alto para o logger
#lembrando a ordem: DEBUG - INFO - WARN - ERROR - FATAL
log4j.br.com.odontonew=DEBUG

#configurando o hibernate no log4j 
log4j.category.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

#### O primeiro appender escreve no console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
### Pattern que mostra o nome do arquivo e numero da linha, porem sem data e hora
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

#### O segundo appender escreve em um arquivo e faz um bkp ao atingir o max 
log4j.appender.fileOut =org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileOut.File=app.log
### Controla o tamanho maximo do arquivo
log4j.appender.fileOut.MaxFileSize=100KB
### Faz backup dos arquivos de log (apenas 1)
log4j.appender.fileOut.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.fileOut.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#####este formato esta em ingles: 2011-04-24 e imprime o nro da linha L
log4j.appender.fileOut.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %5p %c:%L - %m%n
####imprime no formato dia/mes/ano 
#log4j.appender.fileOut.layout.ConversionPattern=%-2d{dd/MM/yy HH:mm} [%t] %5p %c:%L - %m%n
```

I think that just hibernate logging is showing normally because i can see the Hibernate Queries (but it can be because persistence.xml that is configured to show hibernate queries).

So, i try do the code bellow but the console don't show anything.

```
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DentistaMBImpl.class);
if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
            logger.debug("Inicializando componentes no PostConstruct");
```

EDIT 1:
I Changed to: 
log4j.logger.br.com.odontonew=DEBUG

but nothing is logging.

Comment: It is probably not because of the config file.  Make sure that your log4J is configured correctly.  I bet it is simply not run.  Logs of Hibernate means nothing, because Hibernate's `show_sql=true` do the output by itself, not going through logger.

Answer (score 0):

Should this:

```
log4j.br.com.odontonew=DEBUG
```

Be this?

```
log4j.category.br.com.odontonew=DEBUG
```

Categories have to be declared as `log4j.category.whatever`, and I'm assuming that your package is `br.com.odontonew`.

Also, don't use logger.isDebugEnabled() unless you're doing an expensive computation as part of the debug call. You're just burning CPU, since the first thing debug() does is call isDebugEnabled().

Comment: Well, i putted the word-key "category" but continue don't working.

Comment: @Scientist Oops, my bad. I think it should be "logger" instead of category. The way to configure the .properties file is here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html. Make sure that the package name is right, too.